# Visual C++ GetCurrentDirectory() Not Working Properly During Startup

Tags: c++-cli

The program works fine, with an issue.
    GetCurrentDirectory(); 
When this is used during start-up it shows the directory as "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator" whatever be the actual application directory.
If use close the application and run it again it gives the proper directory.
How do you solve this problem without having to write the present directory in a separate file and then reading it.

Comment: Do you have a small sample application? Be aware that using the FileOpen/SaveDilaog will also change the current directory! Also why do you assume that the current directory is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "during startup"?

Answer (score 0):

I would use GetModuleFileName() and then search for the last "\" ,split the string check with the GetCurrentDirectory() , If it does not match I would set the split string as the current directory using SetcurrentDirectory()

Comment: Why do you assume that the current directory is the directory of the application???

Comment: Its written "whatever be the actual application directory"